# Search for an element on another website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a code, which will check in another webpage source code, if the provided value (for example, in input box, activate the check by click on button) is already in option (in select menu), and show an alert if there is one.

I tried doing this in jQuery, but I never tried this before, so I failed. :/
Maybe you have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Not possible with Javascript. Now with some PHP you're in business.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you weren't maintaining the other site, the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) would have prevented it, apart if the other site explicitly allows it by including the good [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) and the only solution would have been to do it server side, where you can query the server as you want.

As you maintain the other site as well, then it's easy : you just have to put the good CORS header to let your first site query it.

Here's a good tutorial on enabling cross origin requests for various server side technologies : http://enable-cors.org/

Once it's done, you simply have to query the server and analyze the page :

```
$.get(otherserverurl, function(html) {
    var myInputVal = $('input[name=somename]', html).val();
    // use the value
});
```

Comment: What if the other site is also my site?

Comment: Then it's easy : add the CORS header as I mentioned.

Comment: CORS isn't supported by all browsers though.

Comment: @Rudie Are you alluding to IE7 ? Old browsers not respecting CORS would simply let the query pass, but you can't make a site just for IE7...

Comment: No, old browsers not respecting CORS would always stop the request. CORS is to fix the accessibility problem, not to add security. Does IE8 respect CORS headers correctly??